# PHP code won't work after adding html taggs

Tags: php, html

So I made PHP code that is used for signature, that is not problem right now the problem is that when I add `<html></html>` tags on the beginning of the code it won't show anything that I have done in PHP. So when I put html tags or make space in front of php there is nothing in page, but when I remove them everything work fine. I'm not expert in PHP so..

```
    <?php

    include_once("functions.php");

    $sign = !isset($_GET['s']) ? 1 : $_GET['s'];

    $uname = !isset($_GET["name"]) ? "None" : $_GET['name'];

    // Connection & Website Settings

    $ftpad = "";

    $ftpuser = "";

    $ftppass = "";

    $comm = "SAMP";

    $weburl = "www.incoming.com";

    $usersdir = "/scriptfiles/Users";

    //

    $ftpcon = ftp_connect($ftpad,4112) or die("Error|I can't connect to the database: $ftpad, contact web master");

    $login = ftp_login($ftpcon,$ftpuser,$ftppass);

    $uname = "";

        $name = $_GET['name'];

        ftp_pasv($ftpcon,true);

        $fhandle = fopen("tempsign_".hash('sha256',"$name").".tmp","w+");

        ftp_fget($ftpcon,$fhandle,"$usersdir/$name.ini",FTP_ASCII);

        $str = parse_ini_file2("tempsign_".hash('sha256',"$ime").".tmp");

        fclose($fhandle);

        $skin = $str['Skin'];

    $rImg = ImageCreateFromPNG("./signs/1.png");

if (file_exists("./signs/skins/$skin.jpg")) 

{

    $skinImg = ImageCreateFromjpeg("./signs/skins/$skin.jpg");

} 

else 

{

    $skinImg = ImageCreateFromjpeg("./signs/skins/0.jpg");

}  

    $cor_black = imagecolorallocate($rImg,0,0,0);

    $cor_blue = imagecolorallocate($rImg,0,0,255);

    $cor_lblue = imagecolorallocate($rImg,30,144,255);

    $cor_green = imagecolorallocate($rImg,69,139,116);

    $cor_red = imagecolorallocate($rImg,220,20,65);

    $cor_wh = imagecolorallocate($rImg,255,255,255);

        $cor_n = imagecolorallocate($rImg,246,74,14);

    if(ftp_size($ftpcon,"$usersdir/$name.ini") == -1 || $ime == "None")
    {
        ?>
        <tr>

    <center><td align="center" valign="top"><img src="logo.png" width="400" height="155" alt="logo" /></td></center>

  </tr>
  <style type="text/css">

body{

    background-color:#000;

    background-image:url(backg.png);

}
.

</style>
        <?php

     echo "<center><br/><br/><br/><br/><font color='#FF3333'>Error | That signature doesn't exist! Possible reasons:<br/><br/></font></center>";

echo "<center><font color='#0FB9FC'>1. You didn't enter your username in field for that<br/></font></center>";

echo "<center><font color='#0FB9FC'>2. You entered wrong username(Example Your_Name)<br/></font></center>";

echo "<center><font color='#0FB9FC'>3. Username that you entered isn't in our databse<br/></font></center>";

return 1;





    }

    else

    {

        ftp_pasv($ftpcon,true);

        $fhandle = fopen("tempsign_".hash('sha256',"$name").".tmp","w+");

        ftp_fget($ftpcon,$fhandle,"$usersdir/$name.ini",FTP_ASCII);

        $str = parse_ini_file2("tempsign_".hash('sha256',"$name").".tmp");

        fclose($fhandle);

        imagettftext($rImg,12,0,11,39,$cor_n,"font.TTF",urldecode($name));

        imagettftext($rImg,12,0,11,79,$cor_n,"font.TTF",urldecode($str['Level']));

                imagettftext($rImg,12,0,173,120,$cor_n,"font.TTF",urldecode($str['Points']));

                imagettftext($rImg,12,0,173,80,$cor_n,"font.TTF",urldecode($str['Hours']));

                imagecopymerge($rImg, $skinImg, 308,6,0,0,80,100,100);

    }



                          if($str['Sex'] == 0) { imagettftext($rImg,12,0,10,122,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Male"); }

                          else if($str['Sex'] == 1) { imagettftext($rImg,12,0,10,122,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Female"); }


              if($str['GM'] > 0)
              {
              imagettftext($rImg, 13,0,5,161,$cor_green,"font.TTF","GameSupport");}
              if($str['Admin'] > 0)
              {
              imagettftext($rImg, 13,0,5,161,$cor_red,"font.TTF","Admin");}

              if($str['Leader'] > 0)

                {

                  if($str['Leader'] == 1) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","LSPD"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 2) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","FBI"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 3) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","CNN"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 4) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","La Cocaina"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 5) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","La Cosa Nostra"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 6) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Terror Squad Crew"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 7) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","GSF"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 8) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Yakuza"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 9) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Russian Mafia"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 10) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Underground Racers"); }

                          else if($str['Leader'] == 11) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Hitman Agency"); }

                }

                else if($str['Member'] > 0)

                {

                  if($str['Member'] == 1) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_wh,"font.TTF","LSPD"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 2) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","FBI"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 3) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","CNN"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 4) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","La Cocaine"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 5) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","La Cosa Nostra"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 6) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Terror Squad Crew"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 7) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","GSF"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 8) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Yakuza"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 9) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Russian Mafia"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 10) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Underground Racers"); }

                          else if($str['Member'] == 11) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Hitman Agency"); }

                }

                else

                {

                  imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Civil");

                }

    ftp_close($ftpcon);

    unset($str);

    unset($ftpad);

    unset($ftpuser);

    unset($ftppass);

    unset($ftpcon);

    unset($login);

    header('Content-type: image/png');

    imagepng($rImg);

        imagepng($skinImg);



?>
</style>
```

Comment: Place below code first line in PHP, try error step again an let me know what is the error message. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: From the closing `</style>` tag at the end, I would suggest that your problems are how you're expecting the HTML (which is itself very dated) to be displayed.

Comment: Your page is not following HTML tag preference and lots of use of incorrect tags

Comment: You're trying to return an image, but then add HTML tags to it. If you expect to see the final image result it won't work because of the HTML tags, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your below code:

```
<?php

//Error reporting section
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);


include_once("functions.php");

$sign = !isset($_GET['s']) ? 1 : $_GET['s'];

$uname = !isset($_GET["name"]) ? "None" : $_GET['name'];

// Connection & Website Settings

$ftpad = "";

$ftpuser = "";

$ftppass = "";

$comm = "SAMP";

$weburl = "www.incoming.com";

$usersdir = "/scriptfiles/Users";

$ftpcon = ftp_connect($ftpad,4112) or die("Error|I can't connect to the database: $ftpad, contact web master");

$login = ftp_login($ftpcon,$ftpuser,$ftppass);

$uname = "";

$name = $_GET['name'];

ftp_pasv($ftpcon,true);

$fhandle = fopen("tempsign_".hash('sha256',"$name").".tmp","w+");

ftp_fget($ftpcon,$fhandle,"$usersdir/$name.ini",FTP_ASCII);

$str = parse_ini_file2("tempsign_".hash('sha256',"$ime").".tmp");

fclose($fhandle);

$skin = $str['Skin'];

$rImg = ImageCreateFromPNG("./signs/1.png");

if (file_exists("./signs/skins/$skin.jpg")) 
{
    $skinImg = ImageCreateFromjpeg("./signs/skins/$skin.jpg");
} 
else 

{
    $skinImg = ImageCreateFromjpeg("./signs/skins/0.jpg");
}  

$cor_black = imagecolorallocate($rImg,0,0,0);

$cor_blue = imagecolorallocate($rImg,0,0,255);

$cor_lblue = imagecolorallocate($rImg,30,144,255);

$cor_green = imagecolorallocate($rImg,69,139,116);

$cor_red = imagecolorallocate($rImg,220,20,65);

$cor_wh = imagecolorallocate($rImg,255,255,255);

$cor_n = imagecolorallocate($rImg,246,74,14);

if(ftp_size($ftpcon,"$usersdir/$name.ini") == -1 || $ime == "None")
{
  ?><tr>
        <center><td align="center" valign="top"><img src="logo.png" width="400" height="155" alt="logo" /></td></center>
    </tr>
    <style type="text/css">

        body{

            background-color:#000;

            background-image:url(backg.png);

        }
    </style><?php

 echo "<center><br/><br/><br/><br/><font color='#FF3333'>Error | That signature doesn't exist! Possible reasons:<br/><br/></font></center>";

    echo "<center><font color='#0FB9FC'>1. You didn't enter your username in field for that<br/></font></center>";

    echo "<center><font color='#0FB9FC'>2. You entered wrong username(Example Your_Name)<br/></font></center>";

    echo "<center><font color='#0FB9FC'>3. Username that you entered isn't in our databse<br/></font></center>";

    return 1;

}
else
{

  ftp_pasv($ftpcon,true);

  $fhandle = fopen("tempsign_".hash('sha256',"$name").".tmp","w+");

  ftp_fget($ftpcon,$fhandle,"$usersdir/$name.ini",FTP_ASCII);

  $str = parse_ini_file2("tempsign_".hash('sha256',"$name").".tmp");

  fclose($fhandle);

  imagettftext($rImg,12,0,11,39,$cor_n,"font.TTF",urldecode($name));

  imagettftext($rImg,12,0,11,79,$cor_n,"font.TTF",urldecode($str['Level']));

  imagettftext($rImg,12,0,173,120,$cor_n,"font.TTF",urldecode($str['Points']));

  imagettftext($rImg,12,0,173,80,$cor_n,"font.TTF",urldecode($str['Hours']));

  imagecopymerge($rImg, $skinImg, 308,6,0,0,80,100,100);

}



if($str['Sex'] == 0) { imagettftext($rImg,12,0,10,122,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Male"); }
else if($str['Sex'] == 1) { imagettftext($rImg,12,0,10,122,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Female"); }


if($str['GM'] > 0){ imagettftext($rImg, 13,0,5,161,$cor_green,"font.TTF","GameSupport");}
if($str['Admin'] > 0){ imagettftext($rImg, 13,0,5,161,$cor_red,"font.TTF","Admin");}

if($str['Leader'] > 0){

  if($str['Leader'] == 1) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","LSPD"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 2) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","FBI"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 3) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","CNN"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 4) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","La Cocaina"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 5) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","La Cosa Nostra"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 6) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Terror Squad Crew"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 7) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","GSF"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 8) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Yakuza"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 9) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Russian Mafia"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 10) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Underground Racers"); }

  else if($str['Leader'] == 11) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Hitman Agency"); }

}
else if($str['Member'] > 0)
{

  if($str['Member'] == 1) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_wh,"font.TTF","LSPD"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 2) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","FBI"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 3) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","CNN"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 4) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","La Cocaine"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 5) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","La Cosa Nostra"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 6) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Terror Squad Crew"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 7) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","GSF"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 8) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Yakuza"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 9) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Russian Mafia"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 10) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Underground Racers"); }

  else if($str['Member'] == 11) { imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Hitman Agency"); }

}
else
{
  imagettftext($rImg,13,0,171,40,$cor_n,"font.TTF","Civil");
}

ftp_close($ftpcon);

unset($str);

unset($ftpad);

unset($ftpuser);

unset($ftppass);

unset($ftpcon);

unset($login);

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($rImg);

imagepng($skinImg);
?>
```